# In javascript, how to freeze a specific propertes of an object?

Tags: javascript

```
Object.defineProperty(window, "customVideo", {
  value: {
    ovaURL: "can-not-change",
    pvaURL: "can-not-change"
  }
});
Object.freeze(window.customVideo.ovaURL);
Object.freeze(window.customVideo.pvaURL);

//but when i run:
customVideo['ovaURL'] = "i-can-change-you-huhhuh";
customVideo['pvaURL'] = "i-can-change-you-huhhuh";

//and console.log
console.log(customVideo.ovaURL);
//so result is : "i-can-change-you-huhhuh" 
//not what i want is "can-not-change"
```

I've used `freeze` function to prevent user to change the value of `window.customVideo.ovaURL` maybe they are not working at this time, or I'm misunderstanding something here. :((

But when I use `freeze` for `customVideo` like `Object.freeze(window.customVideo);`
he will freeze `customVideo` too good, but he's not allowing me to add `customVideo.newProp = 2` to `customVideo`.

I just want to freeze two property of `customVideo` are `ovaURL and pvaURL`, how can I do it?

**WHY I NEED THIS?**

I'm writing chrome extension, and i need to set default and freeze the variable that in the future, his name will create by the scripts of the destination page. This work will allowing me to control the page better when they loaded to visible for users.

Comment: wrap `Object.freeze({...})` around the value object in your OdP call

Comment: i like the simpler `customVideo = Object.freeze({  ovaURL: 1,    pvaURL: 2 });`; why even mess around with Object.defineProperty if you don't need to?

Comment: @dandavis thank you, but this trick still not work as my comment of **thefourtheye** answer.

Comment: This is failing for you because `Object.freeze` doesn't do precisely what you think. `Object.freeze(foo.bar)` freezes the object currently referenced by `foo.bar`, but does not prevent the `bar` property on `foo` from being reassigned (causing it to reference a different object while leaving the previously-referenced object unchanged).